# Password manager with checking for expired logins and passwords

Tags: passwords, login, verification

I, like most in here, use a password manager for keeping all kinds of login/pass informations inside. And over time, the heap of passwords started to grow, and grow, and now it's on about 350 (give or take) entries.

The problem is, most of these have been temporary, for example, for login into forums which I wanted to visit, and never come back again; same with some pages and so on ... and because of that, every now and then I come onto a password that's long gone expired.

***So I was wondering, is there a utility out there that can check which of these has actually expired by logging in, and logging out ?***

I know this is a relatively complicated operation (auto filling doesn't always works and so on, how to log out ... etc.) , but still ... maybe someone knows.

Comment: If you need a one time account on a website (which requires an email address), you can try mailinator.com

Answer (score 1):

None of the password managers I know allow for online checking of password expiration. As you can guess this is implemented differently on each website so it would be very hard to implement.

That said, a couple of password managers do present some functionality that may facilitate this task for you:

[KeePass 2](http://keepass.info/features.html) supports expiration time for its password entries. It also supports Triggers and Scripting, which all together open up interesting possibilities; like automatically opening the associated website when the entry on KeePass expires.

[RoboForm](http://www.roboform.com/) integrates with your browser(s) and allows for quick creation, editing and deletion of its password entries through its browser toolbar.

Comment: It is difficult, I agree. But, let's be frank, 90% of all forums on the net run on what, five or six platforms. So, I'm guessing it would be possible to implement something of a kind, were the demand for it sufficient enough. As far as your options, I'm using KeePass now, I know of its options but it doesn't really help me.

Comment: I can see a possible demand for that, indeed. RoboForm would be a prime candidate for this type of feature. More perhaps than KeePass which isn't much concerned with browser integration. I can give you a little help and add my name to the feature request.

Answer (score 1):

**No.** This is *almost* impossible to implement, and would create security risks.

Answer (score 0):

I find this a bit confusing. I can't imagine why you'd want to do this. Is it to clean up your list of credentials? Is it to make sure your username will not be taken by someone else? If you want to login to a site and find out that you can't, you can probably register again.

Also, I'm not sure why you want this application to log out. It would be easier if it would simply let the session expire.

Anyway, the password manager called Clipperz (it's an online service that also executes in the browser) allows the user to create links to automatically login to web sites. You could open this links (there must be a Firefox addon that allows to open multiple links simultaneously) and check that the web page is open and the user is logged in.

As mentioned in the previous answer, the implementation varies, so it takes some manual work to create the login links.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible...